# The following C program regarding pointers is not working

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int *pc;
    *pc=100;
    printf("\n Address of Pointer : %d",pc);
    printf("\n Contents of Pointer : %d",*pc);
}
```

When I run the code in eclipse, it is saying "Pointers.exe has stopped working". What is the error?

Comment: `pc` is not initialized, but definitely does not point to valid memory. Dereferencing a pointer like this will usually crash. You need to point to the address of another variable or allocate memory with `malloc` (and then `free` when done).

Comment: FWIW, Clang gives me _warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *'_ and _warning: variable 'pc' is uninitialized when used here_. Let your compiler help you.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a value to `*pc` is particularly dangerous. If `pc` contains the valid memory address , then the assignment

```
*pc = 100;
```

will attempt to modify the data stored at that address.
If the location modified by this assignment belongs to the program, it may behave *erratically*; if it belongs to operating system, the program will most likely *crash*.

Your compiler should raise a warning that `pc` is uninitialized.

Comment: For initializing the pointer,Do we need to create another new variable and put that address in the pointer each time??

Comment: @Max_dev, You need *something* valid to point at before you write there. A variable is one option, and it doesn't require cleaning up after it like `malloc` does.

Comment: @Max_dev; It needs a well known memory location for initialization. Either that could be an address of a variable or the pointer return by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
    int a;
    int *pc;

    pc = &a; 
    *pc = 100;
```

Your `pc` pointer was not initialized in your program.

Moreover the way your are printing a pointer value is incorrect, use this:

```
printf("\n Address of Pointer : %p", (void *) pc);
```

Comment: Why do i need another variable ??Can you explain the concept behind it??

Comment: @Max_dev a pointer to `int` is pointing to an `int` object, in your case it was pointing to some random location as it was not initialized.

Comment: Why the cast to `void *`?

Comment: But as per your code, now you are maintaining two copies of same value 100. dont you feel it is redundant??

Comment: @zmbq, Because `printf` requires a `void *` argument for `%p`.

Comment: @Max_dev: There aren't two copies of the value. There is an `int` and a `pointer to int`. The pointer holds the address of `a` and when you do `*p = 100` the pointer is dereferenced and the value is stored in `a`.

Comment: @zmbq, It can't. It specifies that when you use `%p`, the argument you pass must be `void *`. It's up to you to uphold that. You could pass a `double` or something if you wanted, but that's not `printf`'s problem.

Comment: I'm now trying to read on the matter, and can't figure out why. When does (void *)p change the value of p? In fact, when does it generate any different machine code than simply using p (when p is a pointer type) ?

Comment: I think this warrants a stack-overflow question. I'll get right on it.

Comment: @zmbq, It's simpler than that. For `%p`, the standard says *The argument shall be a pointer to void.* Below the list of specifiers is *If any argument is
not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
undefined.*

Comment: When will the stack frame be different? It should be exactly the same, because casting from int * to void * shouldn't change the actual pointer value at all. Anyway, moved this to a different question, it has nothing to do with the question here.

Comment: it does not change the value. it changes only the way printf see this.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to point `pc` to somewhere useful. When you write

```
int *pc;
```

The compiler creates a pointer for you. The pointer points somewhere in memory, and you have no way of knowing where. Chances are, it points to a bad place in memory. When you overwrite it with `*pc=...` you overwrite a place in memory that shouldn't be overwritten.

So you need to have `pc` point somewhere.

```
int a, *pc=&a;
```

will do the trick. Now the compiler prepares an int for you then and you point `pc` to it. That way, when you write through the pointer, nothing bad will happen - you're writing on an area of memory that you know is safe.

Another way to initialize pc is like so:

```
int *pc = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); // Allocate an integer on the heap
```

Now `*pc=100;` will also work. Just don't forget to `free(pc)` when you're done.

Comment: I think you are wrong . '*pc=&a' means that the address of 'a' is stored as value in 'pc'. Will someone code this way?

Comment: pc=&a means exactly that. Now that pc has the address of a, *pc lets you access what is at that address. And yes, people who use pointers use them like that. I'll add another example that might make more sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

> ```
> int *pc;
> *pc=100;
> ```

When you define the pointer to integer `pc` above, this pointer is *not initialized*, so it points to some memory that you have not allocated and you have not the right to access.

So your executable is crashing.

Just use a *valid* pointer, e.g. you can allocate some heap memory using `malloc(sizeof(int))` (and later release it using `free()`), or just use stack-based memory for local automatic variables, e.g.:

```
/* An integer stack-allocated variable */
int n = 64;

/* Pointer to that integer */
int * pn = &n;

/* Change its value */
*pn = 100;
```

Moreover, to print an address, considering using the `%p` specifier for `printf()`.

e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 64;
    int *pn = &n;    

    printf("n (before): %d\n", n);

    *pn = 100;
    printf("n (after): %d\n", n);

    printf("Address of n: %p", (void *)pn);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> n (before): 64
> n (after): 100
> Address of n: 003AF7CC
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Pointers need to POINT! A pointer is a variable that contains the adress of another variable.

```
int *pc;
```

This pointer contains some garbage value. Who knows what was in that memory before. The adress that it's pointing to could be an adress of memory that is occupied by another program. You need to assign a valid adress to a pointer if you want to change the value in that adress.

If you want to calculate sum of all the members of an array you would have to initialize the variable `sum` to 0 because it could contain other values.

The same is with pointers. They have to contain a valid adress of a variable if you want to modify the value.

Your program would work if you comment line `*pc = 100;`. You can display the adress of an uninitialized pointer but the program will crash if you try to change the value in that adress.